# Setting WMI permissions remotely on windows server 2003

Tags: .net, wmi, windows-server-2003

I know this question is related to 'server setting'

but I can't receive any answer (https://serverfault.com/questions/141754/setting-wmi-permissions-remotely-on-windows-server-2003)

this question is close to server setting, but is also very close to programming.  if not  close please

here's the question.

I made a simple program checking the service on the remote server is started or not. by using this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd0y33x(v=VS.90).aspx)

but the permission should be set. and I can't find any document via the internet. except one document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266(VS.85).aspx

but the engineer say that 'tell me exactly what I do. there are many DCOM

are they any nice document to show him?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://servermonitor.tistory.com/50
I found perfect answer
but it is written in Korean T.T

Comment: You can try translating the article from Korean to english (or any other language) with google. http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fservermonitor.tistory.com%2F50&sl=ko&tl=en

Answer (score 0):

Here's one document about troubleshooting WMI permissions and it includes Win2003 instructions:

http://www.ditii.com/2007/08/14/wmi-permissions-troubleshooting/